# Running script on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I am trying to run a python script with facial detection on boot with `rc.local` on a jetson nano with the ubuntu system. The following is the `rc.local` file contents.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/fdetect
python3 scripts/run.py
```

The script utilizes tensorflow and several other libraries like numpy and scipy. The code runs fine when I run it via terminal but on startup, it resulted in a cascade of errors including the following: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'`.

I have tried solutions provided by other stack overflow articles, such as making sure numpy & scipy versions are compatible, but it hasn't solved it. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an environment issue. Remember, you have already logged in as a specific user when you use the terminal. What user is the service running as during startup?

Comment: @KennyOstrom I am not sure, is there a way to specify that or check?